# can we open any image in editor in iOS8?

Tags: ios8

in iOS8, 
what developers need to  do to use image editor which is introduced in iOS8.

Let's say I have an image in our app and i want to open in editor environment, can we do it using photo framework or any other framework. if Yes, then please suggest something.

Comment: Have you actually [read the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html)? All of your questions are answered in some detail.

Comment: Thanks middaparka, apart from extension, do we have some other options?